# PHP file upload of non-persistent PHP files -- safest way?

Tags: php, security, file-upload

I'm trying to write a script that allows the upload of php files for parsing.  Most of the tutorials and security information I can find on Google and here assume you're only allowing the upload of images (so use getimagesize, etc).

How do I confirm a file uploaded is really a PHP file without relying on the headers?  Also -- I don't plan on storing the file in any way, I just want to grab the contents, parse it, and dump the info -- is there a very secure way to just grab the contents without actually saving the file to temp?  If I do have to save it to temp, if I just grab the contents and then quickly delete it, am I still facing security threats and, if so, how do I dampen them?

What sort of sanitization do I need to do to PHP file contents to prevent misuse of the system?  Basically, is there a way for a malicious user to 'inject' running code if I'm just parsing the contents as text?

Comment: Depends on what your "parsing" entails specifically. Why don't you probe for `<?` then? And the *quick* deletion seems superfluous unless your tmp directory is above the document_root.

Comment: The parsing will just be for structure for now, to visualize my objects, methods, properties, and maybe the links between them, check for tightness of coupling - that sort of thing.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to get the content of the file, use file_get_contents(), you get the contents of the file as a string.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php

And then just use regular expression or w/e you use to parse with strings.